# Subconsulta en MySQL, para tabla Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, bootstrap

Muy buenas a tod@s, necesito realizar una consulta dentro de otra, que me entregue un valor sumado
esto es lo que tengo, pero me arroja syntax error, esta es la consulta:

```
select 
ListaEscolar_detalle.id,
ListaEscolar_detalle.id_curso,
ListaEscolar_detalle.cod_articulo,
producto.ARDESC as descripcion,
ListaEscolar_detalle.cantidad,
bodeprod.bpsrea as stock_sala,
(SELECT 
    SUM(inventa.incant)
FROM
    inventa
GROUP BY inventa.inarti) AS stock_bodega,
(ListaEscolar_detalle.cantidad * precios.PCPVDET) as precio_detalle from ListaEscolar_detalle
left join precios on SUBSTRING(ListaEscolar_detalle.cod_articulo,1,5)  = precios.PCCODI
left join producto on ListaEscolar_detalle.cod_articulo = producto.ARCODI
left join bodeprod on ListaEscolar_detalle.cod_articulo = bodeprod.bpprod
left join inventa on ListaEscolar_detalle.cod_articulo = inventa.inarti
where ListaEscolar_detalle.id_curso=49;
```

Ayuda porfa!;(

Comment: porque no usas eloquent?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.